# Не работает сворачивание и закрытие приложения из дочернего окна

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть дочерняя форма. В ее конструкторе передал ссылку на родительскую:

```
MainWindow mv;
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      mv = new MainWindow();
    }
```

и теперь в двух RadioButton -ах

```
Click="RadioButton_Click">
Click="RadioButton_Click_1">
```

- в их обработчиках, которые находятся как и сами RadioButton в дочернем окне -
пытаюсь закрыть или свернуть главное окно, в зависимости от нажатого RadioButton:

```
 private void RadioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mv.Close();

        }



        private void RadioButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mv.Hide();
        }
```

- но, ничего не происходит. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В ее конструкторе передал ссылку на родительскую:

нет, не передали.

Вы создаете новое окно, и вызываете его методы, но оно на экране вообще никогда не появляется.

```
public Window1(MainWindow aMain)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  mv = aMain;
}
```

Предполагая, что `Window1` создается в одном из методов `MainWindow`:

```
Window1 w1 = new Window1(this);
```